# Msi hangs on _RemoveFilePath during Repair

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Each time we run our installer and try to do a repair the msi hangs for 20 seconds. When I run the msi with some logging I can see in the logging in always hangs on _RemoveFilePath.

MSI (s) (40:54) [16:20:08:520]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: _RemoveFilePath
MSI (s) (40:54) [16:20:22:154]: PROPERTY CHANGE: ...

Does anyone have an idea on this?
I cannot find any documentation about this "_RemoveFilePath".

I enabled logging to try to pinpoint where the exact problem is.

Comment: Could you post a larger chunk of the log? Is this by any chance happening during the InstallValidate action? Is it possible that some affected files are in use during the repair? This could cause slowness; see related Q&As here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74548797/wix-installer-slow-because-file-in-use and https://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=35073